# Majority function stability under deletion and addition of entries

Tags: pr.probability, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

It is well known that the majority function is stable under random flipping of bits. That is, if $v$ is a random binary vector, and then we re-sample each bit of $v$ with probability $\delta$ and get $v^{'}$, then $\Pr[Maj(v) = Maj(v^{'})] = 1 - \frac{arccos(\delta)}{\pi}$

However, how will the majority function behave under addition or substruction of entries? Say we delete t random bits of v and add s random bits to get $v^{'}$. Is there any similar connection between $Maj(v)$ and $Maj(v^{'})$ in this scenario?

I conjecture that yes because the two cases are of course equivalent when s=t, however, I'm not sure how the connection behaves as a function of s,t, nor how to formally start to prove such connection.

Thanks!